# Have to quantify ux?

Tags: research, evaluation

I was assigned by the lecturer to conduct a user experience evaluation on an existing website. Then in the question, he asked us how you quantify user experience and heuristic that you will be using for your expert review. I thought ux is about feelings and experience? how do you quantify it? Is it correct if I say by doing research such as questionnaire?

Comment: You've already posted this once before. It was a duplicate then and it still is today. Please don't repost the same question multiple times.

Comment: @JonW the link which you marked as duplicate wasn't helpful at all and it is very complicated i do not understand it as i read through. I wasn't developing a website, my task is to evaluate an existing website. By marking it as duplicate you have blocked my chance from accepting other useful answers such as answer from nicholus hung. he explained it clearly to me and it is what i want. please be considerate before you judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UX is about many things, feelings and emotions are a part of it. IT uses both quantitative and qualitative data to inform design.

As for quantitative, some things you can measure are:

1. Time to complete task
2. How many times a button as clicked, how often users come back to the site
3. Any descriptive information about your audience that can be gathered through surveys, such as demographics
4. Inquiries received by customer service agents (addressing UX issues can lessen resources spent in customer service)
5. Using navigation vs search bar
6. A/B Testing